# Generate all possible object combinations from another object

Tags: c#

Let's say I have the following object:

```
public class Foo
    {
        public int? Prop1 { get; set; }
        public int? Prop2 { get; set; }
        public int? Prop3 { get; set; }
    }
```

Initialized like this:

```
var test = new Foo(){
    Prop1 = 10,
    Prop2 = 20,
    Prop3 = 30
}
```

I would like to generate a list with all the possible combinations of these attributes. 
The following list would be a possible result (basically a list with all the possible combinations):

```
List[0] = new Foo{Prop1 = 10, Prop2 = null, Prop3 = null};
List[1] = new Foo{Prop1 = null, Prop2 = 20, Prop3 = null}
List[2] = new Foo{Prop1 = null, Prop2 = null, Prop3 = 30};
List[3] = new Foo{Prop1 = 10, Prop2 = 20, Prop3 = null};
List[4] = new Foo{Prop1 = 10, Prop2 = null, Prop3 = 30};
List[5] = new Foo{Prop1 = null, Prop2 = 20, Prop3 = 30};
List[6] = new Foo{Prop1 = 10, Prop2 = 20, Prop3 = 30};
```

I was thinking using linq or reflection to try to navigate all the properties and do ....something. Of course it can be done with a lot of manual adds, getting all the combinations by hand and ending with a long code, but I'm sure there is a simpler way to achieve that, so..any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is the order of combinations important?

Comment: what do you mean as the order of combinations? if you mean if I need that List[0] from the example is in the 0 position, no, is not important, it's just an example. The values inside are the object's properties, so you can't change them.

Comment: Yes I meant the order of elements in the final List<Foo> - my answer generates the same combinations as your example above, but in a different order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This **hideous** and **perilous** method will generate your list of combinations for an arbitrary object:

```
public List<T> CombinationsOf<T>(T template)
{
    var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(prop => prop.CanRead && prop.CanWrite).ToArray();
    var combinations = 1 << properties.Length;
    var result = new List<T>(combinations - 1);
    for (var i = 1; i < combinations; i++)
    {
        var instance = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
        var bits = i;
        for (var p = 0; p < properties.Length; p++)
        {
            properties[p].SetValue(instance, (bits % 2 == 1) ? properties[p].GetValue(template) : properties[p].PropertyType.IsValueType ? Activator.CreateInstance(properties[p].PropertyType) : null);
            bits = bits >> 1;
        }

        result.Add(instance);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Usage:

```
var result = CombinationsOf(new Foo { Prop1 = 10, Prop2 = 20, Prop3 = 30 });
```

You can change the outer loop initialiser to `i = 0` if you want the "missing" combination will all default values.

**Warning:** This code is dangerous - it:

- Sets private properties which might break internal state.
- Calls property setters and getters which may run code which cause side effects.
- Will produce the wrong result if there are more than 31 properties as the << operator will wrap and you'll generate the wrong number of combinations...
- ...if you don't hit the OutOfMemoryException that's likely to occur with c. 25 properties and above due to the huge number of combinations.

Comment: I can understand **hideous**, but why do you say **perilous**?

Comment: A very good explanation. Perhaps you should put that in the answer?